# How can I call plugin function from a custom template?

Tags: plugins

I've just developed a calendar plugin.
To display a calendar in a template, I call `do_shortcode(args...);`.

This works fine.

But how can I call a function from my plugin that will return data?

I don't want to use `include_once` - I really just want to call a function E.g.

```
$events = calendar->getEvents(args...)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the data is not included as a shortcode parameter?

Comment: I thought short code only outputted data, not returning data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the plugin is active, the function will work perfectly fine from any template.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me on the right track. What I needed to do, was to create a function in my `my_plugin.php` that called the function I really wanted from `some_other_file.php`. I tried calling that function directly... and that did of course not work :)